# How to convert negative timestamp to date (PHP)

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to convert negative timestamp value to human readable value. This is my code:

```
$timestamp = -30607469951;   

$date = new DateTime();    
$date->setTimestamp($timestamp);

$date->format('j/n/Y');
```

Comment: Well first what date should this negative timestamp be? In the future? Back in the dinosaur epoch ?

Comment: @Rizier123 it comes out to be the year 1000 2nd month 1st day lol

Comment: unless you're on a 64bit PHP, that's not going to work. that value greatly exceeds what can be represented in 32bit PHP.

Comment: You are already doing it.
Negative timestamps are allowed. Maybe change your format is that is what you don't like.

Comment: Marc, you are right. Is there any solution without changing architecture?

Answer (score 1):

All i did was echo out the formatted `$date`, is that what you wanted?

```
$timestamp = -30607469951;

$date = new DateTime();

$date->setTimestamp($timestamp);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```